# Communication in SWARM robotics

Tags: wireless

Hey so I am trying to research into SWARM robotics, and trying to find helpful information or even articles/papers to read on the process of setting up communication protocols between different robots. For instance using a LAN connection, does each robot need to have a wireless adapter, and how would I begin setting up a network for say 5-10 smaller robots?

More generally could someone help me understand how devices connect and communicate across networks? I understand the basics of IP addressing, but I haven't researched into further complexities.

Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Zotto, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

While there are some tricks specific to SWARM and other multi-robot systems communications, it sounds like you need more learning of the basics before any of that would be useful to you. It sounds like you are using 802.11 (or maybe Zigbee based on your other questions). For these, there are lots of good (non robotics) resources for learning basic networking out there if you look for them that will be more useful than any answer you get here.